# Rewriting a filename using a predefined structure with rules

Tags: vb.net

I need some help fist constructing my problem and then coding it.

I'm reading the name of a file, the name of the file is made up using a defined structure let's say:

```
ID1 ## ID2 ID3 ID4
```

Where each ID can be 1 of X amount of strings that can be in a list/table

```
ID1: string1, "string with space", string2 ...
ID2: etc.
ID3: etc.
```

And where *##* is a number

From this i would like to construct a generic name using some predefined rules and also retrieve ID1 and ID4 for further classification.

First i need to retrieve ID1
Then i need depending on ID1 i need to apply a rule for whether the number should be replace by *PM* or *GM*

```
if ID1 = FP and (## = 14 or 16 or 18)
then replace ## by PM
else if replace ## by GM
```

I then need to recuperate ID4, as i want to create a file path that would look like

```
./ID4/ID1/
```

An example of the file names and the path created would be :

```
FP 20 PETIT CHEF BV BIS LORIS        |   
FP 22 PETIT CHEF BV JUNIOR LORIS     |  --> FP PM PETIT CHEF BV LORIS

FP 24 PETIT CHEF BV BIS LORIS        |
FP 26 PETIT CHEF BV JUNIOR LORIS     |  --> FP GM PETIT CHEF BV LORIS

filepath : ./LORIS/FP/
```

From what i see the problem is the different ID can be a string of 1 or more words, so i can't count the number of words. Also it's possible that i have an ID5 ID6, which i need to keep at the end.

I suppose my question is, how can i achieve this?

Do i need to first split my string into different variables using some kind of matching from a list of values?
If so, how can i do that?

Or am i missing something completely?

Thank you

Comment: After `##`, there are several words separated by spaces in your example. How do you know what words belong to which one of the `ID2`, `ID3` and `ID4`? Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  

In my example, i would know that `PETIT CHEF BV` is `ID2` because it would be in my "dictionary" of possible `ID2`  

One other thing, `ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3` are never the same, so 3 different dictionaries. Is that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the `String` variable `line` contains  the `ID1 ## ID2 ID3 ID4`. For example,

```
Dim line As String = "FP 22 PETIT CHEF BV JUNIOR LORIS"
```

Let's say the lists of possible values for `ID1`, `ID2`, etc. are arrays of `String`'s, that is,

```
Dim id1s() As String = { "FP", ... }
Dim id2s() As String = { "PETIT CHEF BV", ... 
...
```

The first task is to identify `ID1`, `ID2`, etc., in `line`. You start with `ID1`. You loop through all its possible values until you find one that is at the beginning of `line`.

```
Dim id1 As String
For Each s As String In ids1
    If line.StartsWith(s) Then
        id1 = s
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If id1 Is Nothing Then
    ' Decide what to do in case line does not start with
    ' a known value.
End If
```

Now you can remove `id1` from `line` as follows before extracting the number and searching for other ID's.

```
line = line.Replace(id1 & " ", "")
```

The next two characters in `line` are the `##`. You can extract them as follows, and remove them from `line`.

```
Dim n As String = line.Substring(0, 2)
line = line.Replace(n & " ", "")
```

You can now extract other ID's just like you did for `ID1` above. Building the final filepath is now easy since you have all its parts in `id1`, `n`, `id2`, etc.

Comment: Cheers Robert, i'm pretty sure that"s what i was looking for. I'll try and create a little sub to see if i can get it working.
Also i presume i can also populate my arrays with external xml or txt files?

Comment: Yes, you can read the contents of files into strings, for sure, see for example [ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8). Glad I could help!